# How do I force Exchange Public Folders to synchronize?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, public-folders

I have 4 copies of a public folder store, two copies in different AD sites residing on 2010 servers.

I'm using Exfolders (the new PFDAVADMIN) for debugging the widespread replication issue.

In exfolders, I've gone to each copy of the public folder (on each server) and did a bulk edit of

- Replicas (to merge and add all 4 servers)
- Sync time (always)

But on one server, I was still getting "no replica available" when I expanded a folder.  As a result I went to each server and selected "propagate replica list".  That force-fixed the replicas.. but still I'm getting not matching contents as illustrated in the image below:

[image]

Note the scroll bar length is different for each.

**Question**

How can I force all copies of all folders to be up to date -without risking losing data?

What might have caused this to be in this state?

Comment: Are you getting errors in the event log?

Comment: @Drifter104 only for activesync, but I just stopped that app pool - there should be no reason Activesync touches this server.

Comment: In your image I'm guessing the two on the left are in one site and the two on the right are in another site? Public folder replication can be very slow. Use this powershell script. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2010-Public-944df6ee Generate a report give it 2 hours and do it again. See if anything has actually replicated in the mean time. You may have fixed the problem and are now waiting for the backlog